# Why does this recursive function return undefined?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm attempting to write a function that combines two strings using recursion. My code is below but I don't know why the function returns undefined especially when I console.log within the base case and it does not print undefined but instead the correct value.

```
var str3=""
function merge(str1,str2){
    if(str1.length==0||str2.length==0){
        console.log(str3)
        return str3;
    }
    else{
        str3=str3+str1.substring(0,1)+str2.substring(0,1);
        merge(str1.substring(1,str1.length),str2.substring(1,str2.length))
    }
}

merge("AAA","BBB") //--> returns undefined but the console.log(str3) gives correct answer
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwbyhkx4(v=vs.94).aspx this has a good basic example. As others are saying, return should do the trick.

Comment: Apart from a missing `return` in the alternative case you have tainted so that consecutive calls will return results prefixed with the last result. eg. `merge("CDE","123"); //==> "ABABABC1D2E3"`

Comment: Did you try walking through your code with a debugger? That would have turned up the problem quite quickly.

Comment: Before merge recursive call, you check whether the number of characters greater than 1 else return from function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Explanation**

The problem is that you don't return the recursive call's result, thus it is undefined when the whole call to `merge` is resolved.

Let me take you through the execution, step-by-step:

1. With arguments `"AAA"` and `"BBB"`, their lengths are not 0, go to else. Once in else, `str3` is `"AB"`, call `merge("AA", "BB")`.
2. With arguments `"AA"` and `"BB"`, their lengths are not 0, go to else. Once in else, `str3` is now `"ABAB"`, call `merge("A", "B")`.
3. With arguments `"A"` and `"B"`, their lengths are not 0, go to else. Once in else, `str3` is now `"ABABAB"`, call `merge("", "")`.
4. With empty string arguments, length is 0. Now go to the if statement, where `str3` is logged, and returned.
5. Since the `merge("", "")` call has resolved (to `"ABABAB"` as it is returned), we continue where we left off in the call `merge("A", "B")`, thus going "up" the call stack.
6. We start where we left off in call `merge("A", "B")`, in the else branch. There are no more statements or expressions in that call, so it's resolved. **There are no return statements, so by default it returns `undefined`**. We go "up" the call stack to call `merge("AA", "BB")` where we left off.
7. We start where we left off in call `merge("AA", "BB")`, in the else branch. There are no more statements or expressions in that call, so it's resolved. Again, there are no return statements so by default it returns `undefined`. We go "up" the call stack to call `merge("AAA", "BBB")` where we left off.

   We start where we left off in call `merge("AAA", "BBB")`, in the else branch. There are no more statements or expressions in that call, so it's resolved. Again, there are no return statements so by default it returns `undefined`. There are no more calls, so everything's resolved - and `merge("AAA", "BBB")` returns `undefined`.

TL;DR: The recursive call is not returned on each call in the else branch, so the value of `str3` is returned to the call `merge("A", "B")`. The call `merge("A", "B")` does not return anything, it returns `undefined`. The same goes for all other calls - they have no return statement in the else branch so `undefined` is returned. When all calls are resolved, `undefined` is returned.

---

**Solution**

The solution is to simply prepend `return` to your recursive calls. That way, the result of each call would be returned, 'delegating' the final returned value of `str3` up the call stack - the call returns `"ABABAB"`, not `undefined`.

Since we now *return* the result of the call, steps 6, 7, and 8 above **now have a return statement**. That means we don't return `undefined`, but instead `str3`. This is because `merge("", "")` returned `"ABABAB"`, which is the value of `str3`. That result is then returned in call `merge("A", "B")` because of the new added `return` statement, which is then returned in call `merge("AA", "BB")`, and so on, until the call is completely resolved, and the returns the value of `str3`.

Here's the new code:

```js
var str3 = "";
function merge(str1, str2) {
    if(str1.length == 0 || str2.length == 0) {
        console.log(str3);
        return str3;
    } else {
        str3 = str3 + str1.substring(0, 1) + str2.substring(0, 1);
        return merge(str1.substring(1, str1.length), str2.substring(1, str2.length)); //we return the recursive call
    }
}

var mergedString = merge("AAA","BBB"); //mergedString is "ABABAB"
```

Before, `mergedString` would have received the value `undefined`. Since we now return the recursive calls, everything returned accordingly thus the value of `str3` is returned, being stored into variable `mergeString`.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/) guide you have to `return` the result of the recursive call:

```
var str3=""
function merge(str1,str2){
    if(str1.length==0||str2.length==0){
        console.log(str3)
        return str3;
    }
    else{
        str3=str3+str1.substring(0,1)+str2.substring(0,1);
        return merge(str1.substring(1,str1.length),str2.substring(1,str2.length))
    }
}

merge("AAA","BBB")
```

Comment: "you have to use the keyword `return` to call the recursive function" --- this is dangerously imprecise. `return` is used to return from a function, to to call something.