# Returning from if statement within function giving undefined

Tags: javascript, if-statement, recursion

My assumption is that the return in the first part of the if statement would break the function and return n, however it keeps giving undefined. If I console.log n it gives me the correct thing. Am I missing something??

Thanks everybody

```
 function digital_root(n) {
   if(n.toString().length === 1){
    console.log(n)
    return true;
  }else{
    var digits = (""+n).split("");
    thing = digits.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b), 0);
    digital_root(thing)
  }
}

digital_root(942)
```

Comment: because your recursion does not return

Comment: You have to return something in the `else` statment! `return digital_root(thing);` will do!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39321807/5647260

Answer (score 0):

You do not return in the recursion so that means it will return undefined.

```
return digital_root(thing)
```

Comment: ...and, of course, the OP also needs to return `n` (instead of `true`) from the innermost function call.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I'm still trying to grasp Javascript recursion...