# Why isn't this factorial function returning?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I created this recursive function that calculates a factorial for a number. The first argument n is the number you want to calculate a factorial for and the second argument result is used to pass the state of factorial calculation to the function when it calls its self. The issue Im having is the function will console.log the correct factorial in result at the end of the function but wont return it. It will only return a factorial for numbers less the 2, all other return undefined. I have a conditional with "n >=2",  so that makes me think that is related to that, however I cant find a any relation between that and the issue. Why is this function not returning the correct factorial?

```
function factorial(n, result){

    //checks if result is undefined if so uses n calculate value of result
    //if result isnt undefined it changes its value using "n * ( n - 1)"

    result = result * (n - 1) || n * (n - 1);



   //decreases n, n gets gradually smaller
    n-=1;


 //if n is more the 2 run function again
 //I'm fairly certain this conditional is the root of the issue but personally cant find the relation
    if(n >= 2){
        //passes current state of n and result
        factorial(n,result);
       }
    else {
       //result has the correct value as its printing to the console 
       //correctly, e.g !4 = 4*3*2*1, which equals 24, this prints 24 if you 
       //pass 4 to n.
       console.log(result);
       //if n is smaller then 2 return factorial
       //but it wont return result
        return result;
        };
}
```

Comment: There is no `return` statement in your `if` branch, so it returns `undefined`.

Comment: change factorial(n,result); to "return factorial(n,result);"  factorial function will only return when n<2 but when n>2 it only calls the function and do not return anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this recursive function return undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39321807/why-does-this-recursive-function-return-undefined)

Comment: ok thanks melpomene and yash Thakor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your function doesn't return the result is becaus eyou aren;t returning the result of `factorial(n, result)` when `n >=2`

```
function factorial(n, result){

    //checks if result is undefined if so uses n calculate value of result
    //if result isnt undefined it changes its value using "n * ( n - 1)"

    result = result * (n - 1) || n * (n - 1);



   //decreases n, n gets gradually smaller
    n-=1;


 //if n is more the 2 run function again
 //I'm fairly certain this conditional is the root of the issue but personally cant find the relation
    if(n >= 2){
        //passes current state of n and result
        return factorial(n,result);
       }
    else {
       //result has the correct value as its printing to the console 
       //correctly, e.g !4 = 4*3*2*1, which equals 24, this prints 24 if you 
       //pass 4 to n.
       console.log(result);
       //if n is smaller then 2 return factorial
       //but it wont return result
        return result;
        };
}
```

However the easiest way to write this code is to recur till a terminating condition is reached

```
function factorial(n) {
   if(n == 1) {
       return 1;
   }
   return n*factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: You simply want to have factorial of number using recursion?

Comment: Your "easy" solution is far worse than OPs tail recursion attempt. `(n, acc = 1) => n <= 1 ? acc : factorial(n-1, n * acc)` is better and never stack overflows in ES2016 implementations.

Comment: @Sylwester: note that although it's in the specification, TCO hasn't really landed in most JS engines.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Only Safari. All other engines lack both ES2015/ES6 and ES2016 features so basically they're ES5 engines with some new addons.